# Can we create multiple projects with same code?

Tags: android

I want to create another android project with same code. But I don't want to copy paste. Is this possible? Briefly, it should be same with creating target in Xcode (IOS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with product flavors.

Simply add a new flavor in `productFlavors` in `build.gradle` and -if needed- change your images, in that flavor's directory.

eg.
Your main code, layouts, images are in `PROJECT_FOLDER/app/src/main/`, and for your new project, they will be in `PROJECT_FOLDER/app/src/NEW_FLAVOR/`